# hosting multiple websites on SBS2008 server

Tags: iis-7

Disclaimer: I'm new to the server end of websites so my question may not be well formed.   I'm also new to working in an SBS (Microsoft Small Business Server 2008) environment so what I think I know may not apply here.

If you're still reading, thanks!  What I'm trying to do is setup a company intranet site on our SBS (Standard Ed) server.  Currently there are a number of sites already configured to run on port 80 so I'm assuming (possibly incorrectly?) that I can add the intranet site on port 80 as  well.  I currently have the intranet running on port 8550 or something along those lines, but my users have to type http: //server:8550 and that's not too intuitive.  I'd like for them to type http: //intranet, or just intranet in the address line and get to where they're going.  I need to know how to redirect a friendly address like http: //intranet or just intranet to the site listening on http: //server:8550 address.

Can this be done?

(sorry for the spacing in the URLs above, I'm a new user and can't post hyperlinks in my questions yet.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get "intranet" registered in your company's DNS and point it at your server.  (Either with an "A" record pointing to the server's IP address, or a "CNAME" record to the server's name.)  Then in your IIS site, add a new host header set to "All Unassigned" IP address, port 80, with a host header of "intranet".  Those 3 values have to be unique across all other websites on the box for it to work.